# Matlab Pade approximation influence on bode plot and step response

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, matlab, delay

I would like to approximate a delay via the pade approximation. I set a normal delay via the exponential term and I set a delay via the pade approximation and I look the difference between the both with a bode plot and a step response. This is totaly different ... So this is not an approximation ... Where is my error ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Have a nice day :)

Comment: There are too few integration points in your step response. Please ensure a reasonable Integration stepsize for the step function and the result will look more reasonable IMO.

Comment: Do `step(sys_retard, 10e-6); hold on; step(sys_retard_pade, 10e-6);` and please update the question with this revised plotting code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) Do you know a way for setting the intregration stepsize ?

Comment: Also do you know why the bode plot of the "pade" delay does not fit with the pure delay ?

Comment: see my second comment. the small `end time` of 10e-6 will hint to matlab that small step size needs to be used. Alternately, give all the time steps and matlab will use that as stepsize; e.g. `step(system, [0 : 1e-7 : 1e-5])`.

Comment: The scale in the phase plot is 5760 degrees!!!! *Uncheck* the "*unwrap phase*" in the options of the bode plot! This plot may be misleading!

Comment: Thank you for your help ! It totally resolve my problems :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Step response

There seem to be too few integration points in your step response. The delay is 2 us while the sampling of the step response seems to be 10 ms. Matlab / Octave should ideally guess the correct step size for the integration. In this case it doesn't.

Below code should hint matlab that a small integration step size should be used.

```matlab
step(sys_retard, 10e-6);
hold on;
step(sys_retard_pade, 10e-6);
```

### Frequency response

The scale in the phase plot is 5760 degrees.
*Uncheck* the `unwrap phase` in the options of the bode plot. Matlab will then wrap the phase of both systems to the -180 to +180 deg range. The phase response will match with that setting (for low frequencies where the pade approximation is valid).

Answer (score 1):

There is no error other than maybe different expectations. The Padé approximation is just that: an approximation, therefore it's limited compared to the "real thing". The key thing to remember is that \$\mathrm{e}^{-st}\$ has an infinity of roots, and the approximation can only ...approximate that through a finite set of roots. How many? However many you can afford. But that will mean that no matter how many roots you can spare, there will always be a limitation of the covered bandwidth, not in terms of magnitude -- that will be an allpass -- but in terms of group delay.

Maybe it will help to regard the Padé approximation not as a Padé series, but a Bessel allpass in disguise. Start with the prototype lowpass and convert it to an allpass:

$$\dfrac{3}{s^2+3s+3}\quad\rightarrow\quad \dfrac{s^2-3s+3}{s^2+3s+3} \tag{1}$$

The lowpass prototype will have a group delay of 1 s, and by converting it to an allpass it will be double, thus 2 s. Constructing the Padé approximation for a 2nd order with 2 s delay will result in:

```
[a,b]=padecoeff(2,2)
a =

    4  -12   12

b =

    4   12   12
```

And if you normalize the denominator it will mean dividing everything by 4, resulting in (1).

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) I did not get it. I agree to say that it will not affect the magnitude as it is a delay, but it will affect the phase (this is actually what I want) and then as it affects the phase by definition of the group delay it will affect the group delay. I agree to say that it is an approximation but with even an order of 7 it completely does not fit ...

Comment: How can I study a system by looking the poles and zeros if the phase is completely changed by adding a delay with the pade approximation ? And it is actually not representative of the phase adding by a pure delay ???

Comment: @Jessa A Padé approximation will never be able to replace \$\mathrm{e}^{-st}\$ *unless* you only need it for a certain bandwidth. For example see [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/567283/95619) that deals with an FIR implementation in analog domain. As long as the bandwidth of interest is not exceeded, it *could* be a replacement, if the side-effects (there's always a price to pay) are acceptable -- the step response will be quite evocative here. It may be less problematic in `.AC`, than `.TRAN`.

Comment: Thank you for your help ! You re totally right :) I was just enable to properly plot my curves and I was surprise by the difference between the curves :)

Comment: @Jess To my shame only now I see the problem with your step response plots: it looks like the timestep is 10 ms or so, but a 1 ms would be more proper; even less, and the timescale could also be reduced.